# Mass file renaming in Csh

Tags: csh

I'm trying to rename all the files in a directory in csh (I'm using FreeNAS).

I thought I had the hang of it until I accidentally prepended to the whole file name so now I have files of the format

```
Veronica Mars - 1x22 Leave It to Beaver.mkv - HDTV 720p
```

and would like them in the format of

```
Veronica Mars - 1x22 Leave It to Beaver - HDTV 720p.mkv
```

I would like to do this purely with a script so that I can ssh in to my box and run it without having to install anything extra.

Answer (score 1):

The most expedient way to do this is probably vidir, which allows you to edit the filenames in a directory in a text editor. You can then use Vim's or Emacs' column editing/search and replace.

You can [download vidir](https://github.com/trapd00r/vidir/tree/master/bin), and here's a [brief introduction](http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/unix_tools_vidir/).

The only caveat is that it's written in perl, not sure if FreeNAS has that available.

Answer (score 0):

Check if rename is available on your system:

```
rename 's/\.mkv/ - HDTV 720p.mkv/' *.mkv
```

EDIT:
Then you have to do some shell script programming (bash)

for i in *.mkv; do j=`echo $i | cut -d . -f 1`; r=$j" - HDTV 720p.mkv"; mv "$i" "$r"; done

Comment: I checked for rename, and sadly it is not.

Comment: I added a shell script to the post which does the renaming.

Comment: Cheers, I'll see if I can convert it to csh

Comment: I am sorry, I have no knowledge in csh scripting. I heard that FreeNAS from a specific version on has bash installed. Maybe this is an option?